# How to select distinct graph nodes by property

Tags: neo4j, cypher, distinct, neo4jclient

I have a database including PlayStation games and it contains games from all regions and platforms. Some of the games from different regions have the same title and platform so I would like to filter out "duplicates". At this time, I don't have region information on each game so the best I can do is filter out by game name and platform.

Is it possible to select distinct nodes by property? I seem to remember that you can return distinct rows based on a column in SQL, but it seems that Cypher applies distinct to the entire row and not just a specific column.

I would like to achieve something like the following:

```
MATCH (game:PSNGame) RETURN game WHERE distinct game.TitleName, distinct game.Platforms
```

The above query if it were valid would return all PSNGame nodes with a distinct TitleName and Platforms combination. Since the above query is not valid Cypher, I have tried returning a list of distinct TitleName/Platforms where distinct is applied to both columns.

The query I have for returning the distinct TitleName/Platforms list looks like this:

```
MATCH (game:PSNGame) RETURN distinct game.TitleName, game.Platforms
```

The JSON response from Neo4j is similar to this:

```
[["God of War", ["PS3", "PSVITA"]], ["God of War II", ["PS3", "PSVITA"]]]
```

The problem I'm facing is that the JSON response is not really an object with properties. It's more of an array of arrays. If I could get the response to be more like an object, I could deserialize without issues. I tried to deserialize as an `IList<PsnGame>`, but haven't had much luck.

Here's my POCO for the `IList<PsnGame>` implementation:

```
public class PsnGame
{
    public string TitleName { get; set; }
    public string[] Platforms { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:
Here is the simplest example of my Neo4jClient query:

```
// helper function for handling searching by name and platform
private ICypherFluentQuery BuildPSNGamesQuery(string gameName, string platform)
{
    var query = client.Cypher
        .Match("(g:PSNGame)");

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gameName))
    {
        query = query.Where($"g.TitleName =~ \"(?i).*{gameName}.*\"");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(platform) && platform.ToLower() != "all")
        {
            query = query.AndWhere($"\"{platform}\" in g.Platforms");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(platform) && platform.ToLower() != "all")
        {
            query = query.Where($"\"{platform}\" in g.Platforms");
        }
    }

    return query;
}
```

Distinct games:

```
var distinctGames = await BuildPSNGamesQuery(gameName, platform)
        .With("DISTINCT g.TitleName AS TitleName, g.Platforms AS Platforms")
        .With("{ TitleName: TitleName, Platforms: Platforms } as Games")
        .OrderBy("TitleName")
        .Return<PsnGame>("Games")               
        .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
        .Limit(pageSize)
        .ResultsAsync;
```

All games (somehow need to filter based on previous query):

```
var results = await BuildPSNGamesQuery(gameName, platform)
        .Return(g => new Models.PSN.Composite.PsnGame
        {
            Game = g.As<PsnGame>()
        })
        .OrderBy("g.TitleName")
        .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
        .Limit(pageSize)
        .ResultsAsync;
```

By using a map, I'm able to return the TitleName/Platforms pairing that I want, but I suspect I'll need to do a `collect` on the Platforms to get all platforms for a particular game title. Then I can filter the entire games list by the distinctGames that I return. However, I would prefer to perform a request and merge the queries to reduce HTTP traffic.

An example of duplicates can be seen on my website here:
https://www.gamerfootprint.com/#/games/ps

Also, the data for duplicates looks something like this:

```
MATCH (n:PSNGame) 
WHERE n.TitleName = '1001 Spikes' 
RETURN n.TitleName, n.Platforms LIMIT 25
```

JSON:

```
{
   "columns":[
      "n.TitleName",
      "n.Platforms"
   ],
   "data":[
      {
         "row":[
            "1001 Spikes",
            [
               "PSVITA"
            ]
         ],
         "graph":{
            "nodes":[

            ],
            "relationships":[

            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "row":[
            "1001 Spikes",
            [
               "PS4"
            ]
         ],
         "graph":{
            "nodes":[

            ],
            "relationships":[

            ]
         }
      }
   ],
   "stats":{
      "contains_updates":false,
      "nodes_created":0,
      "nodes_deleted":0,
      "properties_set":0,
      "relationships_created":0,
      "relationship_deleted":0,
      "labels_added":0,
      "labels_removed":0,
      "indexes_added":0,
      "indexes_removed":0,
      "constraints_added":0,
      "constraints_removed":0
   }
}
```

EDIT: 10-31-15
I was able to get distinct game title and platforms returning with the platforms for each game rolled up into a single collection. My new query is the following:

```
MATCH (game:PSNGame)
WITH DISTINCT game.TitleName as TitleName, 
       game.Platforms as coll UNWIND coll as Platforms
WITH TitleName as TitleName, COLLECT(DISTINCT Platforms) as Platforms
RETURN TitleName, Platforms
ORDER BY TitleName
```

Here is a small subset of the results:

```
{
   "columns":[
      "TitleName",
      "Platforms"
   ],
   "data":[
      {
         "row":[
            "1001 Spikes",
            [
               "PSVITA",
               "PS4"
            ]
         ],
         "graph":{
            "nodes":[

            ],
            "relationships":[

            ]
         }
      }
   ],
   "stats":{
      "contains_updates":false,
      "nodes_created":0,
      "nodes_deleted":0,
      "properties_set":0,
      "relationships_created":0,
      "relationship_deleted":0,
      "labels_added":0,
      "labels_removed":0,
      "indexes_added":0,
      "indexes_removed":0,
      "constraints_added":0,
      "constraints_removed":0
   }
}
```

Finally, 1001 Spikes is in the list once and has both PS VITA and PS4 listed as platforms. Now, I need to figure out how to grab the full game nodes and filter against the above query.

Comment: What does the Neo4jClient code look like for the query?

Comment: You say you want all with distinct TitleName & Platform combi - does that mean if you had: `God of War/[PS3,PSVITA]` and `God of War/[PSVITA]` you'd want both back?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to group all of the available platforms for a game together, but sometimes my data importer creates separate entries for different platforms for the same game.

Comment: And do you have examples like the above, when one game is listed twice with different but overlapping platforms?

Comment: Please see my edits to the question. I included examples of the Cypher queries, Neo4jClient queries, and my website to demonstrate duplicates. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Alright, let's see what we can see !

Comment: I was able to get duplicate games and platforms filtered out, but I don't know how to efficiently filter the PSNGame nodes with my new query.

Comment: OK, do you have an example of the new query?

Comment: Please see my edits from 10-31-15 with the new query.

Comment: hmmm, the problem is (I guess) that you can't just do a `distinct` on the game, because technically, they *are* all distinct as the Platforms are different. As a side note - would doing something like normalizing the DB be doable? i.e. creating just one of each game?

Comment: Yes, doing a distinct match on all games would return each game separately with each field on the node being compared. I could also run two queries and just do the comparison in memory. However, normalization might be the route I need to go ultimately since it will be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
MATCH (game:PSNGame)
with game, collect([game.TitleName,  game.Platforms]) as wow
return distinct(wow)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to select different nodes by property and remove duplicates? If so, it would be something like this:

```
MATCH (game:PSNGame {property:'value'}) RETURN DISTINCT game.property
```

That should remove duplicates and return your node by property.

Comment: This will return a single node with a given property. I would like to return all PSNGame nodes with a distinct TitleName and Platform combination. I'll update my question to be more specific.

Comment: @CameronTinker Try removing `.property` from the end. That will return the entire node,  Currently away from computer so this is untested, but the syntax itself is correct.